# How to import a Microsoft word document to Notes app in Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, import, apple-notes

I am recently using the `Notes` app in `Mac` and it has been wonderful. However, I have a lot of prior notes taken in `Microsft Word` and are saved as `.docs` format.

I want to import them into my `Notes` app.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Notes can't import .doc files directly, though it can import Evernote .enex files & text files.

- .txt
- .rtf
- .rtfd
- .html

You could try saving your Word files as one of these & see which imports best.

[Apple KB - Import your notes and files to the Notes app](https://support.apple.com/HT205793)